# How to tag and reply to welcome a member in a welcome bot Telegram?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have this welcome bot for telegram from github. I would like that every time a new user joins the group in addition to sending him the message it was mentioned and reply to "id has join in group" as the classic group help does.

I attach below the code to work on:

```
@run_async
def send_async(context, *args, **kwargs):
    context.bot.send_message(*args, **kwargs)


def check(update, context, override_lock=None):
    """
    Perform some checks on the update. If checks were successful, returns True,
    else sends an error message to the chat and returns False.
    """

    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    chat_str = str(chat_id)

    if chat_id > 0:
        send_async(
            context, chat_id=chat_id, text="Please add me to a group first!",
        )
        return False

    locked = override_lock if override_lock is not None else db.get(chat_str + "_lck")

    if locked and db.get(chat_str + "_adm") != update.message.from_user.id:
        if not db.get(chat_str + "_quiet"):
            send_async(
                context,
                chat_id=chat_id,
                text="Sorry, only the person who invited me can do that.",
            )
        return False

    return True


# Welcome a user to the chat
def welcome(update, context, new_member):
    """ Welcomes a user to the chat """

    message = update.message
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    logger.info(
        "%s joined to chat %d (%s)",
        escape(new_member.first_name),
        chat_id,
        escape(message.chat.title),
    )
    # Pull the custom message for this chat from the database
    text = db.get(str(chat_id))

    # Use default message if there's no custom one set
    if text is None:
        text = "Hello $username! Welcome to $title "

    # Replace placeholders and send message
    text = text.replace("$username", new_member.first_name)
    text = text.replace("$title", message.chat.title)
    
    send_async(context, chat_id=chat_id, text=text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
```

this is the result I would like to achieve.

[image]

would anyone know how to help me in this simple task? Thank you!

Comment: What’s wrong with the code you currently have? Why doesn’t it meet your requirements? [ask]

Comment: the code that i currently have don't mention and reply to the user who join in the group.
so it don't do anything of the things that i request.

Answer (score 0):

it's complicated code... keep it simple.

you have an event in group `"new chat members"`. so handle this event and send reply with `first_name` and link to the account.

`Pyrogram` example:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import filters


ACCOUNT = '77777777777'
config = 'config.ini'

__client = Client(session_name=ACCOUNT, config_file=config)

def user_link(user):
  USER_LINK = '<a href="tg://resolve?domain={username}">{first_name} : @{username}</a>'
  USERID_LINK = '<a href="tg://user?id={id}">{first_name} : {id}</a>'
  return USER_LINK.format(**user.__dict__) if user.username else USERID_LINK.format(**user.__dict__)

@__client.on_message(filters.new_chat_members)
def welcome(client, message):
  users = ", ".join([user_link(message.from_user.__dict__) for m in message.new_chat_members])
  message.reply(f"Hello, {users}")
```